# How to get orbit decomposition result?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about the orbit decomposition result. Let $G$ be a group and consider the action of conjugate of $G$ on itself. Now, the stabilizer of $x\in G$ is the centralizer of $x$ denoted by $Z(x):=\{x\in G: xg=gx, g\in G\}$. The orbit of $x$ is the conjugacy class of $x$ denoted by $C(x):=\{x'\in G: x'=gxg^{-1}, \mbox{ some } g\in G\}$.

Since the conjugacy classes are orbits for a group operation, they partition the group.
$$
|G|=\sum |C|=|C_1|+\dots+|C_k|
$$
where the sum over all conjugacy classes $C$.

Note that order of orbit is equal to the index of the stabilizer: $|C(x)|=[G:Z(x)]$.

But why can we write that
$$
|G|=[Z:1]+\sum [G:Z(x)]
$$
where $Z=\{z\in G: zg=gz, g\in G\}$ is the centre of $G$.

Comment: Every element of the center is in its own conjugacy class, by definition. Why write $[Z : 1]$ instead of just $|Z|$?

Comment: Note that the sum in the class equation is over distinct conjugacy classes that don't include summing over elements in the center of G. Which elements would have a conjugacy class that consists of one element only? How many of those classes are there? Hope this helps

Comment: @BaselJ. So the definition of the orbit is $\{g\cdot x: g\in G\}$. So the centre of $G$ is $Z:=\{g\cdot x: g\in G\}=\{gxg^{-1}\}$? So there is just on element in the centre? We can write $|G|=|Z|+\sum_{x}[G:Z(x)]$ where the sum over all distinct conjugacy classes?

Comment: @Hermi the centre of G is $Z(G)=\left\{x\in G \mid xg=gx \, \forall g \in G \right\}$ or equivalently  $Z(G)=\left\{x\in G \mid gxg^{-1}=x \, \forall g \in G \right\}$. This group doesn't generally contain only one element, however the conjugacy class of any element of $Z(G)$ is a singleton set (give a justification given the above). In fact if a conjugacy class is a singleton that element must be in $Z(G)$. So when we sum the sizes of the distinct conjugacy classes of $G$, each of these singletons counts once adding them all up we get $|Z(G)|$.What remains are the distinct non trivial classes